# Firefox only loads part of my site's CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I'm developing a site and I have been working in Chrome, IE and on my Android phone. I decided to test the site in firefox and the whole thing falls apart. It appears to me as if all the CSS is not loading, but for the life of me I can't figure out why it wouldn't be.

Live Site:
http://matttucker.onedogdevelopment.com/

In my source code I have something like the following...

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url(....); @import url(....); </style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url(....); @import url(....); </style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url(....); @import url(....); </style>
```

It's my belief that only the CSS files listed in the first style element are being loaded.

**UPDATE:**
Drupal also allows me to aggregate the css and outputs something like the following...

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="..." media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="..." media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="..." media="all" />
```

Even when aggregated, it only appears that if the first stylesheet is being loaded. I have no idea why that would be, especially since it's already working the other browsers.

Any suggestions, pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the CSS errors reported in Firefox, this one jumps out at me:

```
Error in parsing value for 'src'.  Skipped to next declaration.
```

followed by

```
Unexpected end of file while searching for closing } of declaration block.
Unexpected end of file while searching for '}'.
```

The relevant CSS looks sort of like this:

```
src: local("Meta Serif Book"),
     url(/sites/default/themes/one_dog_development_starter/css/metaserif_book.otf) format("opentype"),
}
```

note the trailing ','.  The fact that this ends up eating the rest of the stylesheet looks like a bug in the CSS error handling in Firefox to me; I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748254 to track it.  But fixing the CSS to not have that problem should probably help.

Comment: Thanks for the great detective work Boris! I've fixed my CSS and that seems to have solved 95% of the problem. I have one more display issue in Firefox. This however is likely a separate issue and I'll create a new post if one is needed.

Comment: Sounds good.  Please feel free to file bugs yourself too; just add "bzbarsky" to the CC list on the bug to make sure I see it!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@import`, try using the `href` property of the `style` element:

```
<link type="text/css" media="all" href="URL HERE" />
```

Also, as your CSS is stored on the same domain, you don't need to specify the domain name. Try structuring like this:

```
<link type="text/css" media="all" href="/sites/default/modules/normalize/normalize.css?m2x9bk" />
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `link` instead of `style`? To my knowledge, the `style` tag doesn't have a `href` attribute.

Comment: @KemalFadillah Your 100% correct. I overlooked that when writing the original post.

Comment: I'm using "Drupal 7" as my CMS. Drupal by default does this to get around IE only loading so many stylesheets. Drupal does let me aggregate the CSS and produces the following...   
  
`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="..." media="all" />`  
`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="..." media="all" />`  
  
However the problem still persist. It appears as if only the first aggregate file is being loaded.  
  
I've made the changes to the live site so that you can see it in action.

Comment: @BryanCasler Check your source code. These don't appear to be rendering this way, I can see `@import` in your source code.

Comment: @Curt I just enabled CSS aggregation on my site and I updated the post to reflect that change. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your.css">
```

Comment: I'm using "Drupal 7" as my CMS. Drupal by default does this to get around IE only loading so many stylesheets. Drupal does let me aggregate the CSS and produces the following...   
  
`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="..." media="all" />`  
`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="..." media="all" />`  
  
However the problem still persist. It appears as if only the first aggregate file is being loaded.  
  
I've made the changes to the live site so that you can see it in action.

Comment: can you switch the stylesheets and then post which affect it has? Then we see, if just the first css is being loaded.